# newlistof without numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I need to include a List of Cases to my dissertation in which it appears the name of each case and the page the case is described, but I don't want the cases to be numbered. Is there a way of doing this?

*Fire Case*

LONG DESCRIPTION OF THE CASE

Then on the "List of Cases page", I want it the cases to be listed by their names, like this:

Fire case .......................... 34

Any ideas how to do this?

---

To whomever is curious, this seemed to work for now, at least

```
\newcommand{\listcasename}{List of Cases}
\newlistof{case}{case}{\listcasename}
\newcommand{\case}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{case}
\par\indent{#1}
\addcontentsline{case}{case}
{\protect #1} \par}
```

So,

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tocloft} 

\newcommand{\listcasename}{List of Cases}
\newlistof{case}{case}{\listcasename}
\newcommand{\case}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{case}
\par\indent{#1}
\addcontentsline{case}{case}
{\protect #1} \par}

\begin{document}

\case{Fire Case}
Very long description of the case that takes up a few lines...

\listofcase
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You could call yourself also `Idonthaveanylineofcode` ;-) Please provide a compilable document that shows how your cases are defined and how they enter the `List of Cases`. I assume, you're using `tocloft`, but that's a guessing only

Comment: lol Right now the cases are just in the quote environment. I couldn't find anything similar on the internet, so I have nothing to begin with. 
The document class is `ucthesis-CA2012` and I'm using `tocloft` for something else (to define a list of examples and list of theses, but that's all worked out already).

Comment: Well, no document, not much help then... I don't want to google for strange classes and make guesses how the quote environment is used in order to generate entries to the list of cases  - file...

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be in the quote environment. Also, I don't have List of Cases yet, so I don't know even know how to give you a compilable example. I have list for other things that are numbered. But cases are not numbered. Each case has its own name.. So I guess what I want is a `List of X`, such that when I define the command `\X`, there's an argument for the name that will appear on the 'List of Cases', but not numbers. Any suggestions on how to google to find something kind of like what I want?

Comment: The screenshot shows an unnumbered list.

Comment: By the way, tocloft with a KOMA Class? That doesn't match.

Comment: I didn't want numbers anywhere. I'm new to latex, so I learn by trial and error what works and what doesn't work. So far this has been working, and I'm open to different suggestions! Btw, the final document will use document class`ucthesis-CA2012`

Comment: This class is unknown to us, how are we supposed to help?